# Try to send data from second tab bar item to first and then back to the first one, how can i do it?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with tab bar with 2 items first one is the main tab bar and the second is a built-in camera with a button, when i press the button I want to pass the data to the first item of the tab bar and after its heepend I want to move to the first item tab bar, how can I do it?

//this is a part from the first tab bar item

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ImageView.image = UIImage()
    ageLbl.text = " "
    genderLbl.text = " "
    genderImage.image = UIImage()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(imageToCheck.size)
    data()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Launch.png")!)
    self.title = "Main"
    ageLbl.text = " "
    genderLbl.text = " "


    }
```

//Part of my second tab bar item (Built-in camera)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Camera"
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    prepareTheCamera()
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.stopCaptureSession()

       }


 @IBAction func takephoto(_ sender: Any) {

    takePhoto = true
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func captureAndSendOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if takePhoto {

        let svc = tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! ViewController

            svc.getImage = true

            svc.imageToCheck = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer)!

        takePhoto = false


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you got the image from the `getImageFromSampleBuffer` method change tab bar controller `selectedIndex` to switch to first view controller

```
func captureAndSendOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if takePhoto {
        if let svc = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first as? ViewController,
            let image = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer) {
            svc.getImage = true
            svc.imageToCheck = image
            takePhoto = false
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        }
    }
}
```